# Async pipe with nested iterable in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, asynchronous

I'm using a `<select>` in order to display a list of data which I retrieve from a web service.

This is what the web service returns:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "description": "something"
    }
    ...and so on...
]
```

this is the HTML file:

```html
<select>
    <option *ngFor="let option of options | async" [value]="option.id">
        {{option.description}}
    </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

this is the relevant part of the TS file:

```js
options: Observable<any>;
ngOnInit() {
    this.options = this.http.get('/web/service/url');
}
```

and it works like expected.

However, the web service is changed, and now returns something like this:

```json
{
    data: [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "description": "something"
        }
        ...and so on...
    ],
    page: 1,
    count: 10,
    total: 100
}
```

I'm able to put the `<select>` in work again by subscribing to the get call and binding `result.data` to a property. However, I'd like to keep using the async pipe instead. Is there a way?

Comment: I edited my anserw, check if it is working for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<select *ngIf="(options | async) as _options">
   <option *ngFor="let option of _options.data" [value]="option.id">
      {{option.description}}
   </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

we are making local variable here, and when options are set we create options.

Comment: @Andrea hmm, try now with local variable, should work

Comment: This is working! Your previous reply also work if you add a `?` in this way: `let option of (options | async)?.data`. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think,
service.ts

```
>  public optionsGetAll(): Observable<Options[]> {
>     let headers = new Headers();
>     headers.append('x-access-token', this.auth.getCurrentUser().token);
>     return this.http.get(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.optionsGetAll), {
>       headers: headers
>     })
>       .map((response: Response) => {
>        let res = response.json();
> 
>         if (res.StatusCode === 1) {
>           this.auth.logout();
>         } else {
>           return res.StatusDescription.map(option=> {
>             return new Options(option);
>           });
>         }
>       });   }
```

component.ts

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.ws.optionsGetAll().subscribe(
      options=> {
        this.options= options;
      }
    );
  }
```